# Why is JavaScript so forgiving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, error-handling

I'm new to JavaScript. Recently, I was writing a program and by mistake in the 'for' loop, I made an error in the spelling of `length`. If I would have made this mistake in other languages I must have got an error and the code wouldn't have continued beyond the for loop but in JavaScript, the code got executed and returned null value.

Could someone throw some light on why the below code doesn't throw an error? Why JS is so forgiving?

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.x.lenght; i++)
```

Comment: if you try to access a non-existent property, the result is `undefined` ... javascript likes to coerce values as appropriate ... in this case, undefined is treated as `NaN` - and and Number (even NaN wich is a Number) comparison with NaN is false - therefore the loop doesn't run

Comment: @NathanChampion - there is no (javascript) error in that code - so there wouldn't be any errors anywhere

Comment: It is not an error in Javascript to reference a property that does not exist.  `x = {}; console.log(x.length)` will just output `undefined` which is what you get when you reference a non-existent property.  That's just the way the language was designed.  If you don't like that, you can use TypeScript which will force more specific type declarations and can then be compiled to Javascript to run in any Javascript target environment.

Comment: @JaromandaX That makes sense. Thanks!